# Disabling asp-sessions. Any known issues?

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm in the process of disabling asp-sessions completely from a site. Its quite a large and complex site, but we're not using the session object programatically anywhere, so I'm just curious if anyone know of any "hidden" issue that may occur if you disable sessions? Viewstates, ajax etc? We're using Dundas components for charting and mapping, but they seems to work ok when running on our test servers.

Answer (score 0):

Check the session events in global.asax. There's one for start and one for end. Make sure nothing is happening there, and you should be be good to go. Assuming the Session type is inproc.